# lightning:buttonMenu issue z-index doesn't work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-buttonmenu

I've created a lightning component which has a menu and this is how it opens:

[image]

[image]

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered selected-apps-table slds-table_fixed-layout">
                                <thead>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps" style="width: 25%;">App</th>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps">Category</th>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps">Rating</th>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps">Status Demand</th>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps">Status Supply</th>
                                    <th class="slds-text-title_caps" style="width: 5%;"></th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!dev.selectedApps}" var="app">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="slds-truncate"><img src="{!app.icon}" class="app-icon"/><span class="app-name"><a href="#" target="_blank">{!app.name}</a></span></td>
                                            <td class="slds-truncate">{!app.category}</td>
                                            <td class="slds-truncate">
                                                <aura:iteration start="0" end="{!app.rating}" items="1,2,3,4,5" var="index">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" alternativeText="star" size="x-small">
                                                    </lightning:icon>
                                                </aura:iteration>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="slds-truncate">{!app.demand_status}</td>
                                            <td class="slds-truncate">{!app.supply_status}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <lightning:buttonMenu class="{!app.app_id}" onselect="{!c.itemSelectedOnSelectedApps}" aura:id="selected-apps-menu" alternativeText="Show menu" menuAlignment="auto" iconSize="x-small" variant="bare">
                                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sObjectName != 'Account'}">
                                                        <lightning:menuItem value="removeFromSelected" label="Remove From Selected" prefixIconName="utility:clear"/>
                                                    </aura:if>
                                                    <lightning:menuItem value="createTask" label="Create Task" prefixIconName="utility:edit"/>
                                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sObjectName != 'Lead'}">
                                                        <lightning:menuItem value="createWishlist" label="Create Wishlist" prefixIconName="utility:topic"/>
                                                    </aura:if>
                                                </lightning:buttonMenu>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

I tried to add z-index with !important but it doesn't work.
I realized it's not possible to override css of standard components.

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: can you add code snippetes?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing "slds-table_fixed-layout" from the table solved the problem.